# junit test case for optional parameters

Tags: junit, get, optional-parameters

```
    @GetMapping("/getAllProjectsDetails")
public List<Project> getAllProjectsDetails(@RequestParam Optional<String> projectId,
        @RequestParam Optional<String> createdBy,
        @RequestParam Optional<String> projectDescription,
        @RequestParam Optional<String> projectName,
        @RequestParam Optional<String> technologiesToBeUsed,
        @RequestParam Optional<String> updatedBy,
        @RequestParam("createdDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Optional<Date> createdDate,
        @RequestParam("updatedDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Optional<Date> updatedDate,
        @RequestParam Optional<String> clientId) {
    return projectService.getAllProjectsDetails(projectId,createdBy,projectDescription,projectName,technologiesToBeUsed,updatedBy,createdDate,updatedDate,clientId);
}
```

i have written this get call using optional parameters and now i need to write junit test case for this get call can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as a unit test goes, you should:

- mock the projectService.getAllProjectDetails() since you only want to test the controller method
- set the expected response which would be a hard coded list
- assert that the expected List matches the actual List when running the method you are testing

More info on mocking can be found here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Comment: thankyou, for the response i tried in the same way but iam getting error could you please help me in a elaborate way?

Comment: @Test
 public void getAllProjectsDetailsTest() {
  Project project = new Project();
  project.setProjectId("1");
 
     List<Client> client= new ArrayList();
     project.setClient(client);
   
     project.setTechnologiesToBeUsed("java");
     project.setProjectName("hr-dome");
     project.setProjectDescription("project is based on lms and it is a companies self product");
  project.setCreatedBy("Priyanka");  
  project.setUpdatedBy("Sowmya");
  Date date = new Date();
  date.UTC(2021,11,02,05,30,00);
  project.setCreatedDate(date);
  project.setUpdatedDate(date);

Comment: Mockito.when(projectController.getAllProjectsDetails("1", "Priyanka", "project is based on lms and it is a companies self product",
    "hr-dome", "java", "Sowmya","2021-11-02 05:30:00", "2021-11-02 05:30:00", "1").thenReturn(project);
      Assert.assertEquals(project, projectServiceImpl.getAllProjectsDetails("1", "Priyanka", "project is based on lms and it is a companies self product",
     "hr-dome", "java", "Sowmya","2021-11-02 05:30:00", "2021-11-02 05:30:00", "1"));

Comment: i tried in this way but iam getting errors